# Why are some of my cron jobs not sending deamon emails?

Tags: linux, crontab

My crontab:

```
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=admins@boingoboingo.com
HOME=/
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)  OR
#sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
05 01 * * * /root/backup_scripts/run_backups.sh
45 03 * * * /root/backup_scripts/new_scripts/run.sh> "/root/backup_scripts/new_scripts/$(date).run.log" 2>&1
```

I DO get daemon emails with the run_backups.sh job

I do NOT get daemon emails with the run.sh job, yet I verified it does run

Here's the daemon email for the run_backups.sh:

```
    from    Cron Daemon <root@aapsan01.boingoboingo.local>
to  admins@boingoboingo.com
date    Thu, Sep 30, 2010 at 2:22 AM
subject Cron <root@aapsan01> /root/backup_scripts/run_backups.sh
mailing list    <admins.boingoboingo.com> Filter messages from this mailing list
mailed-by   boingoboingo.com
hide details 2:22 AM (7 hours ago)
[09/30/10 01:05:01] mounting the usb drive
[09/30/10 01:05:09] usbdrive1 is ready.
[blah]blah, blah blah.
[09/30/10 06:41:51] finished syncing drives.
[09/30/10 06:41:53] usbdrive1 was disconnected.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emails are a result of data going to STDOUT or STDERR from your cron job.  The cron job in question has had both redirected to the log file.

```
> "/root/backup_scripts/new_scripts/$(date).run.log" 2>&1
^ redirect STDOUT to file ^                          ^^^^ redirect STDERR to SDTOUT
```

Comment: While the other answer was helpful, yours spelled it out succinctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After you redirect the standard output of `run.sh` to `/root/backup_scripts/new_scripts/$(date).run.log` there is only the error output left to redirect to standard out. Could it be that `run.sh` just doesn't produce any errors?

If you want to see the standard output of `run.sh` use `tee` to save it to file, too.

```
45 03 * * * /root/backup_scripts/new_scripts/run.sh | tee "/root/backup_scripts/new_scripts/$(date).run.log" 2>&1
```

Comment: Are you saying my redirect is stopping the daemon email?

Comment: @Flotsam: No, I was saying that your command (with redirects etc) just produces no output.

Comment: Ok, so the daemon emails only send on error? It is true that the log file is empty and therefore there are no errors, yet I thought the daemon emailed regardless.

Comment: @Flotsam: It only sent on error because you redirected stout to a file and there is nothing left in the stdout stream. And AFAIK `cron` is not sending empty ouputs just for kicks.

Comment: @honk: You're saying (I think) that stderr is not redirected, but it is (`2>&1`).

Comment: @Dennis: No, I wasn't saying that. His whole problem is that he redirects stuff to file before it is even passed to cron.

Comment: Too bad it can't be forked so it goes to both the file and the email!

Comment: @Flotsam: It can be "forked", look at `tee` like I suggested.